# How to display documents like ppt, pdf in Android app without internet

Tags: android, excel, pdf, ms-word, powerpoint

I want to display PDF,PPT, EXCEL, WORD documents with in my application. The files are already stored in sdcard and I want to open these docs even if there is no internet connection.

I found many posts saying to use either Google docs or any pre installed app. I do not want these solutions, because it does not match my requirement. Because my doc should be opened in a custom layout within my application.

I tried with APV (AndroidPdfViewer) for showing pdf. But its Zoom functionality is not working properly. And I used OlivePhone's OfficeDemo for ppt and all. But its JAR files are of big size and I'm getting the error 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Solution?'.

Is there any working solution for these?
Please help me..
Thanking you in advance....

Comment: Did you implement this task. Because I need the same what you posted here. What is the method you are using? Can you help me by giving the solution for this post?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no native API provided by android, you can use some third party APIs to read ppt,pdf and all.

some third party API's are:

[Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

[officeSuite professional 6](http://www.mobisystems.com/android_office/)

Comment: @Jomia:link given in answer

Comment: For Google docs Viewer, we need internet connection but we need it offline. OfficeSuite professional is APK file only. We need library/jar file

Answer (score 0):

You have to install any third party applications. Otherwise no way. Example [QuickOffice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3&feature=search_result), [OfficeSuite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_with_reg&feature=search_result) and [Document to Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogo&feature=search_result)

Comment: I need source code/libraries of these third party applications.